# How to store data, from Firebase, with multiple values for each key?

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My structure on Firebase is like this:

[picture of structure-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy5xv.png)

(Seems like I'm not allowed to embed pictures yet, so they made it a link instead)

As I'm new to Swift, I'm a bit confused here. 
Been walking in circles for this, apparently, easy task.

I'd like to store the data on the users device.
This way, if new data is updated to Firebase, the device will retrieve the new data at logon, not having the user to update the app through App Store.

I've concluded an array of Dictionaries would be the way to go, but how?

My problem is the values.. 
They seem to be downloaded together, in one SNAP, and not in parts. (Like so: "SNAP1: yada yada", SNAP2: ... " and so on)

I need to be able to access, at any time, only one value belonging to whatever key i'd like.

Here's my code (I know it's not complete yet, but I'm stuck):

```
func updateData() {

    var dictArray: [[String:String]] = []


    // Setting the refference and getting the values within a snapshot..
    ref.child(REF_CATEGORIES).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                let categories = snap.key
                let questions = snap.children.allObjects
                dictArray.append([categories : String(describing: questions)])

                }
        }
    })
}
```

Somehow I need to iterate through the values too, but then: How do I merge them (index) with the correct category?

I'm feeling it's right under my nose.. To bad my nose is too big, for me to see :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I need a bit more information. Can you edit your question to include the data structure of your database? Also, can you add specifically what data you want to have in the array of dictionaries?

Comment: First off, your description kind of defeats the purpose of Firebase. Firebase is a live, interactive database; when data changed in Firebase, client apps immediately know about those changes - therefore you don't need to store the data locally (it does have persistence but that's another topic). Reading data with .value reads all of the data in the node - multiple child nodes will be returned. Using .childAdded iterates over them one at a time. Once you have a dictionary from the snapshot, individual children can be access through key: value pairs.  name = dict["name"] as! String for example.

Comment: Hi Jen, and thanks for wanting to help :)

Maybe I misunderstand you, but I have already attached an image of the structure - it's in a link, as I'm not yet allowed to embed images in posts here, due to my rookie'ness :)

Comment: Jay.

I understand what you are saying. 
And I suppose you are right about that.

What I need, is different 'categories' with one or multiple 'questions'.
And each question the user answers, must be withdrawn from the "pool" of questions, as I need them to be random and not repeating.

So what you're telling me, is to structure my Firebase in such a way, that there are answered and non-answered questions, which the app then handles together, to present the way I need it to.

Thanks. I'll have a look into this.

Comment: Yes. Also, please don't post images in questions. Post code and Firebase structures as text only. That way, they are searchable, editable and if we need to answer the question with a structure, we don't have to retype it. Also, links break so that would affect future viewers of the question. You can get your Firebase structure from the Firebase Console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Comment: Just a thought: you could, in each question node have a /user_taken node. There would be child in each node of uid: true for each user that had that question presented. So when you want to present questions, query the questions node for all of the questions that do not contain the uid: true. That will give you the questions the user has not taken and you could randomize from there.

Answer (score 0):

As the Firebase Database is key-value based, you can achieve roughly what you want by giving each value a key which is simply a number. For example:

```
"Key1": {
   "0":"value1",
   "1":"value2",
   "2":"value3"
}
```

You can then easily parse this into an array when you retrieve the data.

**Fun fact:** if you 'number' (they're not actually numbers, they're strings) your keys in this fashion, the Firebase Database will [actually store this as an array under-the-hood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Rm4.jpg), they just always display it to us in key-value form.

Comment: This is not correct. Firebase stores it's data as JSON, not arrays (even under the hood). Also, if you rely on ordering, using keys like that will get you into trouble as suppose you need to 'insert' a value between 1 and 2? Using 1.5 won't work. It's better to leverage a child node to handle ordering, perhaps and index or date for example.

Comment: @Jay you're correct about it not being the most elegant way to store a list, but it's what OP asked for. Also see [this album](http://imgur.com/a/cwTDg).

Comment: Based on the comments, I don't think that answer works. I could be wrong. However, the link in your post is *not* showing that Firebase data is stored as an array under the hood. It is showing an actual Firebase Array as a value, and that value is stored as JSON under the hood. That's an important concept because arrays in Firebase are stored as single values and cannot be edited or added to and the individuals elements cannot be removed. They should generally be avoided as [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: @Jay yeah, you are right, I think it's just a convenience thing that they present it as an array when exporting!